# How to write a SQL query to find average of each value in that column?

Tags: sql

This is my input table ref: input_table.

I need the output table like ref: output_table

input_table:

```
depname   | empno | salary |
----------+-------+--------+
develop   |    11 |   5200 |
develop   |     7 |   4200 |
develop   |     9 |   4500 |
develop   |     8 |   6000 |
develop   |    10 |   5200 |
personnel |     5 |   3500 |
personnel |     2 |   3900 |
sales     |     3 |   4800 |
sales     |     1 |   5000 |
sales     |     4 |   4800 |
```

Output_table:

```
depname   | empno | salary | avg_salary |
----------+-------+--------+------------+
develop   |    11 |   5200 |       5020 |
develop   |     7 |   4200 |       5020 |
develop   |     9 |   4500 |       5020 |
develop   |     8 |   6000 |       5020 |
develop   |    10 |   5200 |       5020 |
personnel |     5 |   3500 |       3700 |
personnel |     2 |   3900 |       3700 |
sales     |     3 |   4800 |       4867 |
sales     |     1 |   5000 |       4867 |
sales     |     4 |   4800 |       4867 |
```

Could anyone write a SQL query for this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `avg()` as a *window function*:

```
select depname, empno, salary,
       avg(salary) over (partition by depname) as avg_salary
from t;
```